# Оборот ", что" и тире

Tags: пунктуация, тире-или-двоеточие

Встречалось такое утверждение, что оборот «, что» легко заменяется тире. В отношении многих ситуаций это выглядит убедительным и уместным. Однако следующий пример несколько озадачил:

«Он/я понял(понимал), что....»;
«Он/я знал, что...»;
«Он/я думал, что…»;
«Он/я полагал, что...»;
«Он/я подразумевал, что...»;
«Он/я представлял, что...»;
«Он/я убеждался, что...».

Интуитивно нахожу, что двоеточие вместо «, что» в данных примерах предпочтительнее. Однако интересно мнение людей знающих, как правильно:

«Он считал — лучше пойти» или «Он считал: лучше пойти» — пример гипотетический, вопрос касается всех аналогичных конструкций.

Не исключаю также, что русский язык достаточно гибок, чтобы обосновать любой из вариантов, но хочу услышать аргументированное мнение.

Ответ найден самостоятельно почти сразу после публикации вопроса, но если будет что добавить, либо возразить по поводу выбора правила  — буду признателен за уточнения и поправки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По всему вероятию, только что найденное правило исчерпывающе отвечает на мой вопрос:

[§ 45.7](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827528.html)
Тире ставится, если вторая часть бессоюзного сложного предложения (нередко — неполное предложение) имеет изъяснительное значение (перед ней можно вставить союз что), причем в первой части не содержится интонационного предупреждения о последующем изложении какого-либо факта (ср. § 44, п. 3): Овца же говорит — она всю ночь спала (Кр.); Иногда мне думается — надо убежать (М.Г.); …Слышит — за кустами бузины девушка хохочет (М.Г.); Тишина была такой полной и угрюмой, а небо таким душным, что мальчику казалось — раздайся хоть один только резкий звук, и в природе произойдёт что-то страшное (Кат.); Вчера на соседнем зимовье рассказывали — мед ведь человека задрал (Арб.); Слышу — опять стонет (Па— уст.); Движение приостановлено, будем надеяться — ненадолго; Кто-то скребётся, мне показалось — мышь; Но вижу — не слушает она меня; Пишут, чтобы мы обязательно приезжали — будут встречать; Они знали — будет буря; Отстань, не видишь — я занят.